# select "non valid" file extensions

Tags: sql, file, advantage-database-server

Using Advantage Arc to try and get a list of files from a table where there isn't a valid file extension. I want to look for anything that doesn't contain a "." in the name, which I can do with:

```
select *
from filelist
where filename not like '%.%';
```

I now want to extend this out so I can pick up anything that has the ".", but is not followed by 3 or 4 characters at the end, thus hopefully picking up other non valid extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
select *
from filelist
where filename not like '%.____' and
      filename not like '%.___'
```